# Working with a python array full of array

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, sorting

Ok so I have an array of arrays. I'm currently wondering if I'm better to export all of it in my mysql database and do the sorting once there, or work with the array itself.

Here is part of the array:

```
datas = [['Anonymous User-b82a42', 'DYDXUSDT', 'Short', 20, 258.2, 2.332, 2.333, -0.26, -0.8573, '2022-11-16 14:02:28'], ['Anonymous User-b82a42', 'OCEANUSDT', 'Long', 20, 4732.0, 0.13113, 0.13145, 1.51, 4.8688, '2022-11-16 09:04:04'], ['Anonymous User-b82a42', 'CHZUSDT', 'Short', 20, 2684.0, 0.22187, 0.22637, -12.08, -39.7579, '2022-11-16 11:10:17'], ['Anonymous User-b82a42', 'DUSKUSDT', 'Long', 20, 6636.0, 0.09043, 0.09007, -2.38, -7.9724, '2022-11-16 12:40:17'], ['Anonymous User-b82a42', 'CTSIUSDT', 'Long', 20, 5614.0, 0.1062, 0.1058, -2.22, -7.4594, '2022-11-16 13:47:25']...]
```

Here is the things I need to do:

- For the same symbol data[1], get the biggest leverage data[3] and remove/don't save the others
- If 2 symbol data[1] have the same direction data[2], but not the same leverage data[3], keep only the biggest
- If 2 symbol data[1] have the opposite direction data[2] but same leverage data[3], delete/skip/don't save both

The thing I face is it seems a lot to processes from the array itself.
And the case I have multiple same symbol data[1], if I do a for each trade loop, I will maybe delete trades that are valid compare to others but in this loop with this trade it's not.

What should I do? I understand sorted() can be used but I can't find the way to achieve the things I need to do and I wonder if I better save all to mysql and use sql query to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this storing in 2 database tables and comparing them after.